# Javascript this object and bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
new Something({
    events:{
        load: (function loopsiloop(){

            console.log(this);  // firstime this will be Something, but next call what its

            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'foo.htm',
                    context: this,
                    success: function( response ){
                        // do something with the response
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        // do some error handling.  you
                        // should probably adjust the timeout
                        // here.
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        loopsiloop(); // recurse  //need to bind this here like loopsiloop().bind(this)
                    }
                });
            }.bind(this), 5000);
        }),
        click: function(){
            alert("clicked");
        }
    }

})
```

Please go through the code and read comments, here the problem is i need to use `this` in `setTimeOut` function, so I am binding `this` to `setTimeOut`, but when I am calling function as recursive the value of `this` will not be same

NB:- I dont want to pass the object to the function and dont want to use `setIntervel` (http://www.erichynds.com/javascript/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern/)

Comment: I believe you're looking for [**jQuery.proxy**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/): `setTimeout($.proxy(function(){}, this));` will set `this` as the context of the function called by `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Pioul `.bind` does exactly the same job as `$.proxy`

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you, didn't know there was a native `bind` function in modern browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call can be written like this:

```
complete: function() {
    loopsiloop.call(this);
}
```

to ensure that the context is correctly set the second time around.

It could also be written like this, but it's not recommended as it'll call `.bind` over and over on each pass:

```
complete: loopsiloop().bind(this)  // NB: no function wrap, just passes the ref
```

Comment: Just a quick note that [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) is not widely supported yet. The first option is preferable for the time being.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens the OP is using `.bind` within his own code already, but even so I think the former would be preferred

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind and don't use `this`. Set `var someVariable = this;` before you call `setTimeout` and let it remain in scope for the recursion (using it instead of `this` inside the function).

Comment: i think that may be cause problem with memory.

Comment: from where I can assign `this` to any variable ??. Please check the code ... `this` is the reference of `Something`